# Entity Framework confiusing behavior when pulling data from db into list

Tags: entity-framework, linq

If I try to get parts from a machine into the machines list of parts from the db, I execute this:

```
Machine ma = new Machine();
ma = dbcontext.Machine.Where(s => s.Guid == guid).ToList()[0];

IQueryable<Part> PartsQuery = from m in db.Machines
                                    where m.Guid == guid
                                    from p in m.Parts
                                    select p;

ma.parts.AddRange(PartsQuery.ToList());
```

I get double the Parts into my parts list of the machine than actually are in the database!

If I do this instead of the last line:

```
List<parts> partsFromDb = PartsQuery.ToList();
ma.parts.AddRange(partsFromDb);
```

the amount of parts in the ma.parts list is correct. Can someone explain that to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you trying to do in one round trip to your database:

```
Machine mab=context.Machine.Include(m=>m.Parts).FirstOrDefault(m=> m.Guid == guid);
```

About your issue, that's probably is due to the caching policy of EF and maybe Lazy Loading is involve too. I don't know how you are testing your code, but if your do the following:

```
  Machine ma = context.Machine.FirstOrDefault(m=> m.Guid == guid); 

  IQueryable<Part> PartsQuery = from m in db.Machines
                                where m.Guid == guid
                                from p in m.Parts
                                select p;

 PartsQuery.ToList(); //materialize your query but don't save the result;
 var parts=ma.parts;// now take a look here and you will see the related parts were loaded
```

That should be the reason why the data is duplicated, because when you materialize your query and consult later the navigation property (`m.parts`), the related entities are already there. But anyways the best way to get what you need is using the query that I show at the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Machine ma = new Machine();
ma = dbcontext.Machine.Where(s => s.Guid == guid).ToList()[0];

IQueryable<Part> PartsQuery = from m in db.Machines
                                    where m.Guid == guid
                                    from p in m.Parts
                                    select p;

ma.parts.AddRange(PartsQuery.ToList());
```

Is 100% equivalent to:

```
// 1. Find and retrieve the first machine with the given GUID
Machine machine = dbcontext.Machine.First(s => s.Guid == guid);
// 2. Again, find and retrieve the machines with the given GUID, select the parts of each machine that matches and flatten it down to a single list.
IList<Part> machineParts = db.Machines
                                .Where(m => m.Guid == guid)
                                .SelectMany(m => m.Parts)
                                .ToList();  
// 3. Add.. all of the parts to that machine again?  
machine.parts.AddRange(machineParts);
```

So it makes sense that you end up with double the parts inside the retrieved machine.

To be honest, I don't believe that the last change you speak about, i.e. capturing the 'PartsQuery' into a temporary variable, makes any difference with regards to the end result of your `machine`.

Something else must be going on there.

Comment: Hello, Why is this: IList<Part> machineParts the same list than this: machine.parts for you?

Comment: And yes it does behave exactly as I described it. What I forgot to mention is that I use the mysql entity framework provider.

Comment: uhm sorry, I did a typo there. Forgive me please, of course i replaced the lists. silly me ^^

Comment: Well the only scenario in which `machine.parts` from step 1 could be different than `machineParts` from step 2 is if there are multiple machines with the same GUID in the database (and that sounds horrible) or if you managed to pollute the EntityFramework DbContext with two machines with the same GUID. But if you properly configured your DbContext (via property annotations or EntityType configurations) then this shouldn't be possible.